# Complete file name does not appear while downloading via servlet

Tags: java, servlets, download

I have a servlet where I have written code to download a file.

The part of code is as follows :

```
response.setContentType((mimetype != null) ? mimetype
            : "application/octet-stream");


    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="
            + fileName);

    OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
    try {
        //here getFileByte is a method for getting 
        byte bytes[] = getFileByte(filePath);
        os.write(bytes);
}
```

The above works fine but the only problem is that when the filename contains more than one word then it downloads the file with the first word.

> For example:- Filename is "Step by Step.pdf" then the downloaded file
>   will be "Step.pdf".

I even tried to print the filename before giving it to `setHeader method` and it was correct. Don't have any clue how to resolve this.Could anyone please check what am I doing wrong here and how to correct this bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your file has spaces in it, it should be enclosed in double quotes:

```
Content-disposition: attachement; filename="file with spaces.whatever"
```

Note that double quotes will work equally well for filenames *without* spaces, so you might as well use them all the time

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to encode your filename ? For exemple, replacing spaces by "%20" character sequence ?